# Is this a good database design practice?

Tags: sql

I got a `Person` table, each `Person` can visit several countries. The countries visited by each `Person` is stored in table `CountryVisit`

**Person**:

```
PersonId,
Name
```

**CountryVisit**:

```
CountryVisitId (primary key)
PersonId (foreign key to 'Person.PersonId')
CountryName
VisitDate
```

For the `CountryVisit` Table, my primary key is `CountryVisitId` which is an `identity` column. This design will result in that a `Person` can have only 1 `CountryVisit` but the `CountryVisitId` can be 40 for example. Is it a better practice to create another surrogate key column to act as an identity column while the `CountryVisitId` be a natural key that is unique for each `PersonId` ?

Comment: Why not have `person`, `country` as independent tables and a mapping table `CountryVisit`? That way you ensure that countries don't have variations in spelling.

Comment: Yes, that is in my original design, i just made a simpler design here to clarify my question

Comment: What do you want to store if the user visit the same country multiple times ? IE: is this a 1-n or n-n relationship ?

Comment: It's an N:N relationship

Answer (score 8):

It is pretty good.  I would suggest that you have a separate table for countries, with one row per country.  Then the `CountryVisits` table would have:

```
CountryVisitId PrimaryKey,
PersonId ForeignKey, 
CountryId ForeignKey,
VisitDate
```

This will ensure that the country name is always spelled correctly and consistently.  If you want a list of countries to get started, check out this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) page.  Also note that your definition of country may be different from the standard list of countries (there are actually several out there), so you should use your own auto-incremented primary key, rather than using the country code.

And, you should relax the requirement and remove the unique or primary key on `PersonId, CountryId`, unless you want to enforce only one visit per country.